# Core 2.0 MVC - AD Group Authorization for logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, .net-core-2.0

I have a Core 2.0 MVC project and I am stuck on logging.
Is there a way to implement a Windows AD (Active Directory) Authentication and Authorization on the .NET Core 2.0 Framework?
I've seen this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth) using IIS, however I'm looking for a more programmable way. 
(lots of examples for MVC4 and 5, however I couldn't find any for Core 2.0)

Comment: You meant authentication using Active Directory, not Windows Authentication right? The idea would be to use form authentication on the front, and then use active directory as user store at the back. I just answered one of the questions here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46853920/net-core-authentication]. Let me know if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: @DavidLiang I'll take a look at it first thing tomorrow morning! :)

Comment: @DavidLiang that helped me. You could give it as a reference answer and I'll approve it! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use form authentication on the front, and use Active Directory as user store on the back.

I answered a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46854212/2410655